# Is it possible to retrieve a java object from a JSOBject?

Tags: jxbrowser

I have injected a java object into jxBrowser.  When this is done, this java object is wrapped into a JSObject, correct?  I then call a java function passing as parameter to a 'run' method this JSObject that is wrapping the java object.  The object is correctly received; however I want to call a java method with, as argument, the original java object.  Is there a way to extract this object?

A simplified code "example" is:

```
interface Callback {
   public Object run(String function, Object obj)
} 

class JavaCallback implements Callback {
   public Object run(String function, Object obj) {
     // call the function passing obj (convert the function name to an
     // actual function with reflection - not shown - and call it)
     return function.call((Array) obj);   
}
```

The function call will not work as obj is a JSObject and the function is a Java function expecting an Array and not a JSArray.

Thanks...

Comment: Right now this functionality isn't implemented in JxBrowser. We are going to add this possibility in one of the next versions. Probably in September 2016. Please subscribe to our [Release Notes](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/discussions/forums/9000110576) feed to get information about new releases.

Comment: Just downloaded version 6.7 of jxBrowser.  The feature to extract the java object from JSObject is not yet implemented.  I don´t want to seem rude or pushy, so I´m just asking(!) if you could consider it for the next release.  jxBrowser is great and helping a lot and being able to extract the java object would really help.  Thanks!!

Comment: This functionality will be available in 6.8 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now solved in version 6.8.